# Image Segmentation in flutter using tenserlite model

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, computer-vision, image-segmentation, flutter-image

Can anybody suggest me how can I extract segmented image in flutter . I was able to use tenserlite model
for segmentation but i don't know how i can extract  that segmented image from it.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to do image segmentation. So I did a lot of search. And I found one open source.
https://github.com/kshitizrimal/Flutter-TFLite-Image-Segmentation

Comment: I already saw it but it just segments image with color any idea about extracting out only segmented image.